# How do I send output from the terminal to a text file in Visual Studio Code with the proper encoding?

Tags: character-encoding, visual-studio-code

I'm having issues sending output containing Unicode box-drawing characters to a text file.

The string `┌───top───┐` prints to the terminal fine using the print command. It also renders properly if I open and write directly to a file in my code.

However, if I pipe the terminal output into a text file using
`<run command> > out.txt`, I get the result

```
ΓöîΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇtopΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÉ
```

Everything else prints fine, but why doesn't it handle certain Unicode characters?

Is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: It depends on the command you use, you're not piping the *terminal* output, but your *command* output. What command are you using for the redirect? On which OS?

Comment: Windows 10 on most recent VScode, running golang code using the command e.g. `go run main.go > out.txt`.

Comment: Ok, so then the next question is how you print/write those characters to STDOUT . Go is typically quite good at it, so see first if VS Code can guess the encoding by itself. You can do that by setting `files.autoGuessEncoding` in the VS Code settings to `true`